# Why do I have the error BadImageFormatException while running AForge.Video.FFMPEG?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge

I'm trying to edit videos using C#, I found the library AForge.Video.FFMPEG, which seems perfect : easy and complete enough for my use, but, when I try to run the code :

```cs
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace VideoTries
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VideoFileReader vFReader = new VideoFileReader()
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error :

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=03563089b1be05dd'. Attempting to load an incorrectly formatted program.
```

I don't really know what to do, I tried many other libraries, but didn't find any that worked for what I wanted, I even thought the library wasn't free (hence the PublicKeyToken) but obviously that wasn't the case.

I really don't know what to do, if you have any idea of what could help thank you.

Hava a nice day :)

Comment: The `BadImageFormatException` is usually raised when you mix 32 and 64 bit assemblies. The `PublicKeyToken` has nothing to do with free or paid libraries.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into that, but the issue is that to pass time I've been working on another project and I have this error ``Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)`` with a library that worked this morning...

Comment: Do you know if the FFmpeg libs are 32 bit or 64 bit? Do you know how to change your .NET project from 32 bit to 64 bit?